# Get text/URL inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text and URL of a div when a user clicks in it. I am going to pass off the data to a PHP so that I can create a page that shows some other information.

```
<div class="superman">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <h4 class="partnum">PN123456</h4>
      <h4 class="model">Product 456</h4>
      <img src="http://company.com/456.jpg" id="thumb">
</div>
<div class="superman">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <h4 class="partnum">PN234567</h4>
      <h4 class="model">Product 123</h4>
      <img src="http://company.com/123.jpg" id="thumb">
</div>
```

I need to grab the part number, model, and the image URL for each div (class=superman). I have been successful at getting the part number and model, but things fall apart when I try to grab the image URL within the same function. When I can get the image URL, I am not able to retrieve the part number and/or model.

As an example, I've used this to grab the URL (I append as sort of an alert).

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().append($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

I've also tried the getElementById constructions, but those only grab the info in the very first div; if someone clicks on a div further down the page, it still only grabs the first one. I am working on about 5,000 divs, so I don't know if assigning an ID to each div makes sense. I also tried some sort of the (this) construction, but I am too much of a rookie to get things going.

I've seen some questions with answers that approach what I want to do, but, like I said, it's either the part number and/or model, or the URL, but never both. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `$('img').click(function(){
var partnumber = $(this).parent().find('.partnum').text();
})`

Etc....

Comment: you should not (can not) use the same `id` attribute more than once, in your example you have `id="thumb"` twice (once on each image), this is the reason why you only get one element from `getElementById`, it is assumed to be unique. What you should be using is for example a class (`class="thumb"`) and select it with `$('.thumb')` (or `document.querySelectorAll('.thumb')` for vanilla js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having a hard time getting the partnum or model associated with an image, you can retrieve the sibling elements with jQuery's [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

Then, for example, you can concatenate the values and display them.

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  var partnum = img.siblings('.partnum').text();
  var model = img.siblings('.partnum').text();
  var url = img.attr('src');
  var text = 'partnum: ' + partnum + '<br>' +
    'model: ' + model + '<br>' +
    'url: ' + url + '<br>';
  img.closest('.superman').append(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="superman">
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <h2>Info</h2>
  <h4 class="partnum">PN123456</h4>
  <h4 class="model">Product 456</h4>
  <img src="http://company.com/456.jpg" id="thumb">
</div>
<div class="superman">
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <h2>Info</h2>
  <h4 class="partnum">PN234567</h4>
  <h4 class="model">Product 123</h4>
  <img src="http://company.com/123.jpg" id="thumb">
</div>
```

To make the entire div clickable, just change the event handler's selector and use the div as the context of all of the selectors within its function:

```
$(function() {
  $('.superman').click(function() {
    var superman = $(this);
    var partnum = $('.partnum', superman).text();
    var model = $('.model', superman).text();
    var url = $('img', superman).attr('src');
    var text = 'partnum: ' + partnum + '<br>' +
      'model: ' + model + '<br>' +
      'url: ' + url + '<br>';
    superman.append(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: This one seems to be working. So, to move this to the next step, I think I would remove the append line [img.closest('.superman').append(text);], and just pass the variables onto my script that takes them and sends them to a PHP I have waiting.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that entire DIV is clickable and not just the IMG?

Comment: @PatrickL I updated the answer to include an example in which the entire `div` is clickable.

Comment: Nice. This is doing exactly what I need. I did find one typo in the response: `var model = $('.partnum', superman).text();` should be `var model = $('.model', superman).text();`.

Comment: @PatrickL Nice! I updated the answer to fix the typo you found.